# Finding the temperature sensors in a room

Tags: cooling, temperature

It feels very cold in my workplace. They set the temperature to 70F which is below the comfort level, and it is a nuisance to wear a jacket all the time. I am thinking of locating the temperature sensor and sticking a block of ice(regularly replenished from the refrigerator) over it so that it stops blowing cold air into the room(there is no way to close/seal the vents as they are distributed all over the room). Before somebody gets all judgemental, many coworkers have complained of feeling cold - and we must not forget "saving the planet/energy crisis".Is there any practical way to do this? Would a stud locator work? And in your experience do they install these in an accessible location(not on the ceiling)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Industrial HVAC


Answer (score 1):

The HVAC systems of most buildings are controlled by [thermostats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermostat). However, in most offices and other public buildings, the thermostats are not accessible to the visitors. They are typically located out of sight, in areas where access is restricted, or they are physically protected in some other way.

[image]

Comment: Interesting to know that a simple thermostat hidden away in some alcove or in the wall controls the cooling for the whole floor/building. I had assumed that some kind of sampling actually in the rooms was done

Comment: @user15906 it is quite possible that there are multiple temperature sensors/thermostats in your building/on your floor. this is common for industrial/commercial HVAC systems.

Comment: It varies quite a bit, often by the age and way the office was built. Newer designs are more likely to have per-room settings, and older designs are more likely to be zoned (several rooms grouped together controlled by one thermostat). The really bad places are where renovations have happened (adding/removing walls) but the HVAC system was never really considered, and you'll end up with one room too hot and one too cold but both in the same zone so you can't adjust temperature for one without making the other unbearable. These problems can be quite expensive to fix correctly.

Comment: And a lot of office thermostats are [fake](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB1042577628591401304)

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's no obvious thermostat looking objects on the walls. In that case the sensor might be a circular or round plastic panel somewhere on the wall or ceiling. 
I would just talk to the building though. Seems like the easiest solution... It's also very likely that the problem is that the system is not balanced well. 70 seems like a comfortable temperature, but it could be that it actually gets much colder in you area. But if you were to adjust the thermostat, it would get too hot elsewhere